# Get all ManyToManyField-Entries of an object in models.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to have a tag list in the admin panel of my simple blog app. ManyToManyFields aren't allowed as input for `list_display` so i want to create a method for getting the tags and put this method in the list.

My problem is that i don't know how i can access in my model the other class.

My models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

    publication = models.DateTimeField()

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=9999)

    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    commentsAllowed = models.BooleanField()

    def getTags(self):
        return Post.tag.all()    <-----------------------------------

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

My admin.py

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date_hierarchy = 'publication'
    list_display = ('author', 'title', 'publication', 'getTags')
```

This returns me `<django.db.models.fields.related.ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor object at 0xb8e24fcc>`, but i want the tag names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `self.tags.all()`, as it is the instance that has the relationship, not the class.

Answer (score 1):

`list_display` expects its items to be either object (instance) or admin class methods. In both cases they should return something that can be casted to `unicode`.

I would rather put this in admin class like this:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('tags',)

    def tags(self, obj):
        return u", ".join(obj.tag.all())

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super(PostAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).prefetch_related('tag')
```

I added a `get_queryset` method to modify the queryset in such a way that the tags are now prefetched using a single query. Thanks to this, there are not **x** queries for **x** rows displayed in admin.